# Jenkins plugin can't access file on node

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Through my own plugin, I need to know about the existence of a file in the workspace of a Jenkins node. But the file can't be found whereas it really exists on the node (`D:\workspace\JOB_NAME\test.txt`).

```java
public class MyBuilder extends Builder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild<?, ?> build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) 
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            
        FilePath fp = new FilePath(build.getWorkspace(), "test.txt");

        String result = fp.act(new FileCallable<String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String invoke(File file, VirtualChannel channel) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                if (file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()){
                    return file.getName() + " exists.";
                } else {
                    return file.getName() + " doesn't exist.";
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

Result:

```
FATAL: remote file operation failed: D:\workspace\JOB_NAME\test.txt at hudson.remoting.Channel@182752b:Node
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: D:\workspace\JOB_NAME\test.txt at hudson.remoting.Channel@182752b:Node
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:900)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
    at com.company.tlb.proj.MyBuilder.perform(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper@18b91cb
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:166)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.<init>(UserRequest.java:62)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:671)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:893)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.PrintStream
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest._serialize(UserRequest.java:155)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:164)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Links:**

- [Making your plugin behave in distributed Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Making+your+plugin+behave+in+distributed+Jenkins)
- [Jenkins API: FilePath.java](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/?hudson/FilePath.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're passing an anonymous inner-class to `act(...)` which has an implicit reference to its parent class, `MyBuilder`. My guess is that even though `MyBuilder` implements `Serializable`, it can't actually be serialized due to some reference to another object that isn't `Serializable` (e.g. a `java.io.PrintStream` as the stack-trace indicates).

Make your instance of `FileCallable<String>` a static inner class to get rid of the implicit reference to its parent:

```
private static class MyFileCallable implements FileCallable<String> {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Override
  public String invoke(File file, VirtualChannel channel) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()){
      return file.getName() + " exists.";
    } else {
      return file.getName() + " doesn't exist.";
    }
  }
}
```

And then use that instead:

```
String result = fp.act(new MyFileCallable());
```

**Update:**
Here's a link to Java's [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tutorial which outlines the relationship between an instance of an inner class an its enclosing outer class instance:

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance.

This is also explained in more technical terms in the JLS ([§8.1.3 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)).

With that in mind, this quote from the [`Serializable` doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) explains why you encountered the `NotSerializableException`:

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not
>   support the Serializable interface. In this case the
>   NotSerializableException will be thrown and will identify the class of
>   the non-serializable object.

Comment: That was that... thank you so much. Before I award you with the bounty, could you point me out to an official doc explaining this subtlety? I can't find what to tell to Google!

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert Glad I could help! Updated my answer with additional references.

Comment: Great post. Enjoy this +125!