# How can i convert a FilePath to a File?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin and i'm using `build.getWorkspace()` to get the path to the current workspace. The issue is that this returns a FilePath object.

How can i convert this to a File object?

Comment: @Downvoter I don't understand why some people just -1 without saying why. I think we should tell the guy/girl to post some code, ask what they've tried so far, and so on. Just provide some feedback so we can all learn something from this experience.

Comment: **Question:** why do you want a `File` object? `FilePath` is actually a pretty expressive API, and is specifically built for handling remote file operations. If  you try accessing the workspace using `File` on a remote slave agent, you're "gonna have a bad time".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the **act** function and call your own **FileCallable** implementation if your plugin should work for master and slaves. For more information check the [documentation, chapter "Using FilePath smartly"](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html) or this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18006333/1646364).

Code example ([source](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html)):

```
void someMethod(FilePath file) {
    // make 'file' a fresh empty directory.
    file.act(new Freshen());
}
// if 'file' is on a different node, this FileCallable will
// be transferred to that node and executed there.
private static final class Freshen implements FileCallable<Void> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    @Override public Void invoke(File f, VirtualChannel channel) {
        // f and file represent the same thing
        f.deleteContents();
        f.mkdirs();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Although I haven't tried this, according to the [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html) you can obtain the URI from which you can then create a file: `File myFile = new File(build.getWorkspace().toURI())`

Comment: If you need the path as a string, use `build.workspace.getRemote()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your very constructive challenge to that answer of mine! May the upvotes be with you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This approach
`File myFile = new File(build.getWorkspace().toURI())` is not the correct solution. I don't know why this has been an accepted anwser till date.
The approach mentioned by Sascha Vetter is correct, taking the reference from official Jenkins [javadocs](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html)

,which clearly says and I quote

> Unlike File, which always implies a file path on the current computer, FilePath represents a file path on a specific agent or the controller.

So being an active contributor to Jenkins community, I would reference the answer given by Sascha Vetter.

PS. Reputation point criteria makes me unable to up-vote the correct answer.